# JQuery Auto Complete - Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, autocomplete

Struggling with the JQuery AutoComplete ... Could be simple error, but I cant see it.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

is the error message that keeps appearing.

The javascript files declared at the top are :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" />
```

The HTML:

```
<p><label>Country:</label><input type='text' name='country' value='' class='auto'></p>
```

Usage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    //autocomplete
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
        source: "autocomplete.php",
        minLength: 1
    });                

});
</script>
```

**autocomplete.php**

```
<?php

define('DB_SERVER', 'dummytext');
define('DB_USER', 'dummytext');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'dummytext');
define('DB_NAME', 'dummytext');


if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $return_arr = array();

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";port=8889;dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM country WHERE name LIKE :term');
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $return_arr[] =  $row['name'];
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }


    /* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}

?>
```

Any help on this will be much appreciated!

Comment: Type `$.ui` in the browser console. If jQueryUI is being loaded, it will print the ui object, with version, funtcions, and so on

Comment: Sorry, how would I go abouts doing that? @Andre

Comment: fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qLmyz0xr/ is working. Where do you put your code? Before or after the script inclusion? Also, to open browser console, press F12

Comment: @JohnKiller Hi John, the JQuery files are in the head, and the script to carrry out autocomplete is at the bottom

Comment: Can you try what @Andre suggested?

Comment: @JohnKiller if its literally below the error message and enter, I get the following: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function(anonymous function) @ :258f.Callbacks.o @ jquery.js:2f.Callbacks.p.fireWith @ jquery.js:2e.extend.ready @ jquery.js:2c.addEventListener.B @ jquery.js:2
$.ui
undefined

Comment: @Frog82 in the console, inside the developer tools. Depends on what browser you're using, but I think it's F12 for both chrome and IE

Comment: Are you serving your page in HTTPS and got a mixed content warning?

Comment: @JohnKiller The website uses http://

Comment: @Frog82 try changing the version to from 1.10.1 to 1.10.4, full new link: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: @Andre No change sadly

Comment: @Andre I had duplicate JQuery declaration which was causing this issue! problem solved!